# Ruby on Rails: How to include js file in js.erb?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, view, include

I am trying something like below in edit.js.erb which is not working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/myjsfile.js"  </script>
    myfuncinjsfile();
```

Comment: Even if you could include the javascript file, you don't have a guarantee that the file will be loaded by the time you call `myfuncinjsfile`. You should seriously reconsider this approach, it's very messy!

Comment: @Alex: What are other possible alternatives.

Comment: @Maddy put it all in one file

Comment: Include that js file from the start. Or, slightly messier but saving loading one more js file on a user's first visit, use a conditional which includes the javascript file only if the user is on a certain controller (and) action.

Comment: @austinbv: I need to use some js functions in two js.erb files. So "put it all on one file" is not a option.

Comment: @Alex: option you are suggesting is quite messy. Down the line, as number of files grow, there will be lots of such conditional statements. Just like layout/application.html.erb is included in all views, there should be some local layout option.

Comment: Yes, as I said it is. I expect the problem lies more with the way you're organising your javascript. Putting the javascript you require inside a js file that's *already loaded* when the .js.erb file is loaded will mean that the function you require is available for the erb file to call.